# Search queries on open data sites

Tags: data-request

What are people searching for on open data sites?

Just like Google Trends, I am looking for some statistics or even just examples of what search phrases people are using on https://catalog.data.gov/dataset or any other open data sites.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit broad, since you say *or other open data sites.* Depending on the open data site, people will use different search phrases. And one a meta site like you link to (or this one) it could be anything. Why are you asking?

Comment: I am working on a project in the NLP area, and I want to analyze what people are searching for. I think the question is simple, just like on Google Trends, where you can see popular searches, I want to find the same for open data sites.

Comment: I think this is a valid meta-meta-question: 1) find sites that allow people to search for data in a variety of non-subject-specific areas, 2) which of those sites publish their queries, 3) profit-- no, sorry, collate those queries find a general trend.